# Combobox and System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I have a method that is called when the main form is opened

```
private void populateComboBoxes()
{
    SqlCeDataAdapter breakfastAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT recipeName FROM Recipe WHERE Category = 'breakfast' ", databaseConnection);
    SqlCeDataAdapter lunchAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT recipeName FROM Recipe WHERE Category = 'lunch' ", databaseConnection);
    breakfastAdapter.Fill(breakfastDS, "Recipe");
    lunchAdapter.Fill(lunchDS, "Recipe");
    cmbBox1.DisplayMember = "recipeName";
    cmbBox1.ValueMember = "recipeName";
    cmbBox1.DataSource = breakfastDS.Tables["Recipe"];
    cmbBox2.DataSource = lunchDS.Tables["Recipe"];            
    cmbBox2.DisplayMember = "recipeName";
    cmbBox2.ValueMember = "recipeName";                      
}
```

which essentially populates the two comboboxes based on the SELECT statements. Once this method hits `cmbBox1.DataSource = breakfastDS.Tables["Recipe"]` it stops executing and moves to this method:

```
private void cmbBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    rtbPicture.Visible = false;
    string qry = "";
    qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ingredientName FROM Recipe WHERE recipeName = " + cmbBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(qry, databaseConnection);
    com.CommandText = qry;
    rtbRecipe.Text = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

This method is supposed to execute the select statement and put that information in the `richtextbox`, but for some reason `cmbBox1` isn't set. From my understanding the first `combobox` already had set the display and value members in the previous method. However, when I get to the `cmbBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` it returns `System.Data.DataRowView` instead of the actual string in the `combobox`. I'm not sure why it's giving me `System.Data.DataRowView` instead of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `cmbBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`. 
You should probably be using `SelectedValue` instead:

```
qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ingredientName FROM Recipe WHERE recipeName = " + cmbBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

`SelectedItem` gets the actual `ComboBox` item (in this case a `DataRowView`), whereas `SelectedValue` gets the value of the property you specified as the `ValueMember` of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! How do I get `cmbBox1.DataSource = breakfastDS.Tables["Recipe"]` from triggering a combobox change? I only want to enter that second method if they actually select something from the combobox.

Comment: @Lohkii, thank you. Regarding your query, try using the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead of `SelectedIndexChanged`, you should find that only fires when the user chooses a value in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Btw @Lohkii, if you are happy with my answer and it solved your problem (as you indicated), could you please mark the question as answered?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

cmbBox2.DisplayMember = "recipeName";

cmbBox2.DataSource = lunchDS.Tables["Recipe"];

cmbBox2.ValueMember = "recipeName";

Comment: A little brief, could you explain yourself in a little more detail for others to understand.