# A form is loaded but how to extract data from SQL to combobox?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

*Still learning C#*

A comboBox is created and Tables called mainCat and subCat is created.

I have a code , but i am stuck to understand on how to get the data from mainCat to the comboBox , which is then used by another comboBox for the subCat to set a subcategory.

The Get Connection is underlined red. Why?

Here is my code -

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con;
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds1;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection Con = GetConnection())
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Category.Category ,Category.Id from Category", Con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from MAINCAT");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        mainCatU.DataSource = dt;
        mainCatU.DisplayMember = "Category";
        mainCatU.ValueMember = "Id";
        mainCatU.Text = "<-Please select Category->";
        myComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    }

}
```

So i then i tried another code.. but still doesnt work..

```
public partial class User : Form
{
        System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con;
        System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds1;

        private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Database connected");
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            string sql = "SELECT * from MAINCAT";
            da = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(ds1, "SCSID");
            mainCatU.DataSource = ds1;
            con.Close();
            mainCatU.Text = "<-Please select Category->";
            mainCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            mainCatU.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

then i just used the data bound item function through the combobox GUI..

```
this.mAINCATTableAdapter.Fill(this.masterDataSet.MAINCAT);
```

but , the box didn't show any value , except "System.Data.DataRowView" in the comboBox

==================================================================================

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con; //not used at the moment
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter da; //not used at the moment
DataSet ds1;

private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Database connected");

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from MAINCAT", conn);
    ds1 = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds1, "MainCat");
    mainCatU.DisplayMember = "maincat";
    mainCatU.ValueMember = "maincat";
    mainCatU.DataSource = ds1.Tables["MAINCAT"];

}
```

===============

and the combo box is still not showing anything from the database table

Comment: The intellisense should tell you why, but at a guess, does `GetConnection()` exist?  If so, please post the code for it

Comment: ah.. no.. i dont think it exist.. is the code correct by the way?

Comment: I believe it'll compile if you create the connection function

Comment: SqlCommand (and possibly SqlDataAdapter) are disposable, so should probably be in Using statements

Comment: that's the problem.. i dont understand it there.. i mean , how do i create that "getconnection" function?

Comment: Why is your code for querying database within SelectedIndexChanged combobox when that query doesn't depend on the selected index?

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic Good spot. Dependant on how he handles the data is going to affect how an answer would be given. For me I always use a Data Access Layer, or follow the MVVM approach if WPF. But correct, having this in the SelectedIndexChanged event is highly inefficient.

Comment: As stated , i am really new to this.

My forms is in trouble right now , some kind of error , so i had to redo everything back , i'll get back to this when i'm finish recreating everything.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625479/combobox-and-system-data-datarowview

Comment: @pm_2 - i put that into the formload , isnt?

Comment: The reason that it's displaying System.Data.DataRowView is that by default, when bound, controls simply display the `ToString()` of whatever you bind them to.  In your case, that class.  The linked post illustrates how to bind to a specific field.

Comment: @pm_2 - i'll add some answer.. editing now..

Comment: @pm_2 - fixed the code.. :) it shows 1 now.. but it didnt show all the categories inside..

i have 5 categories

Comment: I've updated my answer.  It may be worth you having a look online for a tutorial for basic ADO.NET

Comment: Also, when you do get this working, don't forget to put your using statements back in so that you allow all this to be disposed and garbage collected.

Comment: it worked.. :D but with a different sets of code based on these codes.. :D

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the function `GetConnection()`:

```
public string ConnectionString { get; set;}

public SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    return cn;
}
```

TBH, unless you want to do something in `GetConnection`, you might be better just creating it inline:

```
using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
```

EDIT:

Based on your revised question, I think the problem now may be here:

```
mainCatU.DisplayMember = "maincat";
mainCatU.ValueMember = "maincat";
mainCatU.DataSource = ds1.Tables["MAINCAT"];
```

My guess is that your table structure is not maincat.maincat.  The display and value members should be set to the field name that you wish to display.

Comment: oh , ok.. i just need to get the data from database to the combobox..

I'll try this in a sec..

Comment: +1, Connection strings should be inline, with it wrapped in a using statement. The GetConnection function in this instance shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Are you getting the same issue?

Comment: @pm_2 - hei , i got it working.. :D.. thx for the help.. :) took a few adjustment here and there though.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry I am a vb developer but the concept is same to populate data into combo using sql is

Declare SQLConnection Declare SQLDataReader Declare SQLCommand

```
Try
    If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = Con
    cmd.CommandText = "Select field1, field2 from table"


    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    ' Fill a combo box with the datareader
    Do While dr.Read = True
        ComboBoxName.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
        ComboBoxName.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1))
    Loop

    Con.Close()
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)

End Try
```

Hope it works for you.